# NodeJS: calling global.gc() doesn't reduce memory to minimum?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, v8

To investigate memory leaks, I have setup a route that triggers `global.gc()` at every `POST /gc`

```
app.post('/gc', function(req, res){
     global.gc();
});
```

However, I've noticed that if I spam this request, it reduces the memory usage more and more each time. Shouldn't calling `global.gc()` **once** is enough to reduce the memory to **minimum**?

If so, why does calling multiple times consecutively **reduces memory at every call**?

(I'm using Node.js v0.12)

Comment: How (and when) do you measure memory consumption?

Comment: @Bergi The application is connected to PM2, I measure the memory in real-time using `pm2 monit`. I waited for the memory to climb pretty high (1G). I then send `global.gc()` signal a few times. Each time it reduces memory by around 30-200Mb, until it hits an absolute minimum of ~80Mb. So it took like 10 calls for a full garbage collection, which contradicts what it should do (full garbage collection in one shot).

Comment: This is due to the way how v8 gc works (sweeping) have a look into this great article about the gc http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection

Answer (score 3):

At a very high level, V8 splits up GC into two parts. Looking for garbage to collect, and actually collecting the garbage. Calling `gc()` only does the second part, collecting already-found garbage.