# How to reduce memory to minimum with global.gc() in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

I found the related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178227/nodejs-calling-global-gc-doesnt-reduce-memory-to-minimum)

But still don't got the real answer for this. :(
So, How to reduce to minimum memory with global.gc() in nodejs?
should I spam global.gc() function to reduce?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of forcing the garbage collector to run, you should first identify if you actually have a memory leak by using various tools (e.g. node's built-in inspector, `heapdump` module, etc.) available for node that allow you to detect such leaks.

It's entirely possible that it *appears* there is a leak when there isn't, due to how V8's garbage collector works (it is generally lazy because GC is not exactly a cheap operation CPU usage-wise).

Also, you *can* limit the amount of memory used by V8 via the `--max-old-space-size=xxxx` command-line argument (where `xxxx` is the amount of memory in megabytes). This can also be helpful in more quickly determining whether you have a legitimate memory leak.

Comment: Calling the GC a few times per second would probably also have a huge impact on performance.